# How to understand which checkbox is selected?

Tags: php, sql

i want to select a lot row of my database and have checkbox to any of rows that the user can choose any of them.then i should update database according to user choice, but i can't understand who of this checkbox is selected.

thanks a lot...
the semicode is here:

```
$query  = "Select * mytable limit 30;";         
$res = $mysql->ExecuteStatement (array ());
echo '<form method="post" action="">  ';
$b=0;
while ($rec=$res -> fetch())
{
    echo '<input type="checkbox" id="$b" name="checkboxName[]" value="yes"/>';
    $checkboxID = "number_".$rec["ID"].":";
    echo $checkboxID;
    echo $rec["column1"]."</br>";
    $b++;
} 

if(isset($_POST['formSubmit'])) //this code just get us how many of checkbox are chosen not who are chosen
{
   foreach($_POST['checkboxName'] as $selected)
   {
       echo $selected."</br>"; 
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some thing like this:

Provide a class to all checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="MyChkbox" id="$b" name="checkboxName[]" value="yes"/>';
```

In JS:

```
$('.MyChkbox').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        var checkedId = $(this).attr('id');
        // checkedId will contain the checked checkbox id in it. Use it as per your need
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi In these case you should pass the `Id` of row as value of `Checkbox` and then get them when `form` is `posted` so you can try this

```
 echo '<td><input type="checkbox" class="MyChkbox" id="$b" name="checkboxName[]" value="' . $rec["ID"] . '"></td>';
```

these will have `value` as `row` `ID`